# Bash if condition doesn't match when comparing particular string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Bash if condition doesn't match when comparing particular string

## Matching string:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

## Code:

```
machineOSVersion="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)"

modifiedOSVersion="CentOS Linux release 7 OR Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)"

if [[ ${machineOSVersion} = *"${modifiedOSVersion}"* ]]; then

    echo -e "match"

else

    echo -e "doesn't match"

fi
```

I expected this to match, but it does not.

The same code works with other strings. Is this failing because of `(` or `)` character in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have variable matching reversed. You have to use `*` matching around subset variable not the superset variable.

Use:

```
[[ $modifiedOSVersion == *"$machineOSVersion"* ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got the 2 variables in the comparison backwards. You have to write the conditional as follows:

```
if [[ ${modifiedOSVersion} = *"${machineOSVersion}"* ]]; then
```

You can think of this like that: `${modifiedOSVersion}` is the largest of the two strings, so you need to add stuff to `${machineOSVersion}` to match it. This additional stuff is represented here by the two `*`.